# svn update VS git merge

Tags: git, svn

svn update command automatically resolves conflicts if two developers have modified same files. If I appended a line at the bottom while my collegue inserted a line in the middle. When I try to update from remote repository, my change is still at the bottom with updated file.

How this can be handled in git? Everytime I merge, I have conflicts because of simple changes from multiple developers on the same files.

Comment: This is not a git issue. You would have the same merge conflicts with SVN if you have divergent histories. Despite this facts, git is completely different from SVN, comparing both is not possible. You have to be more precise in your specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVN and Git apply incoming changes in the same way: non-overlapping changes (local and remote) are applied without conflict, overlapping changes will produce merge-conflicts.

Both tools calculate context-aware *chunks of changes*. They do not examine text as single-lines. If the width of the context in Git is bigger than that of SVN (default for SVN is 3 lines), you'll get different results for the same sources. Otherwise merging in Git and SVN should give the same results.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to merge using mergetool. It suggested merged version automatically that need to be accepted.